# Protecting variable inside of markup for asp:Hyperlink Navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation

I have an asp.net repeater control with a series of asp:hyperlink's

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="name" NavigationUrl="~/Pages/display.aspx?fileid={0}&user={1}" />
```

and then on the OnItemDataBound method:

```
fullname.NavigationUrl=string.Format(name.NavigationUrl, user.fileid, user.userid);
```

So that gives me a series of URLs in the repeater
http://www.abc.com/users.aspx?fileid=1&userid=10
http://www.abc.com/users.aspx?fileid=2&userid=20
http://www.abc.com/users.aspx?fileid=3&userid=30

OK, so with a simple proxy tool someone can replace either of the parameters with some OTHER number to get access to what they shouldn't see.
server-side validation and authentication aside, is there a better method other than passing parameters when trying to create a dynamic URL within a repeater?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, create a LinkButton, have it post back to the server, then get the information you need (which may need to be loaded from the db) and do a Response.Redirect instead.

If you expose the querystring, it can always be changed.  Other approach I seen used is encrypt the querystring params, and decrypt on the other page.  If decrypt fails, it was tinkered with.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt parameters as already mentioned by Brian. The other thing you could look into is [Cross Page Postback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx) . The other alternative is to set the parameters in the session cookie, do a redirect on code behind and pick up the params on the target page.